# UITable View doesn't reload

Tags: uitableview, nsmutablearray, reloaddata

I have a UITableView that is put onto a view based app.  it is wired up properly because I can initially send it data.  The problem is clearing the table.  I can clear the NSMutableArray but the data still shows up in the table.

```
-(void)logout {
NSLog(@"LOGOUT");

[friends removeAllObjects];
NSLog(@"%@", friends);
[tableView reloadData];
}
```

and here is the cell for row at index path:
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}

// Set up the cell...
NSString *cellValue = [friends objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;


return cell;
}
```

Comment: Whats your method that returns the number of rows in a tableview look like?

Comment: - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [friends count];
    
    
}

Answer (score 0):

Create a dedicated reference

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableViewReference;
```

Reload that reference in the logout method.